# How to create a list using Stream Api from two lists in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have these objects:

```
class Object1{
int id;
int Onject2id;
int Object3id;
...
}

class Object2{
int id;
...
}

class Object3{
int id;
...
}
```

I have two lists that `List<Object1> object1List` and `List<int> object2IdList`.

I want to create a new list that contains `object3Id`'s which `object1List` has `object2IdList`. (Sorry for my bad language).
I mean I want to collect `Object3` ids from `object1List` which `Object1` has `Object2` ids in `object2IdList`  with stream API (lambda expressions).
I did this with nested for loops before. But it was not a best practice:

```
for (Integer object2Id  : object2IdList)
            for (Object1 object1 : object1List )
                if (object1.getObject2Id().equals(object2Id)) {
                    newList.add(object1.getObject3Id());
                    break;
                }
```

Any suggestion about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact translation of the `for loop` would result in

```
List<Integer> Object3IdList = object1List.stream()
                                             .filter(object1 -> object2IdList.stream()
                                                                             .anyMatch(i -> i.equals(object1.Object2Id)))
                                             .map(object1 -> object1.Object3id)
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this runs in O(N^2). We can convert the list to a Set to make it efficient.

```
Set<Integer> object2IdSet = new HashSet<>(object2IdList);

List<Integer> Object3IdList = object1List.stream()
                                         .filter(object1 -> object2IdSet.contains(object1.Object2Id))
                                         .map(object1 -> object1.Object3id)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
Set<Integer> object3Ids = object1List.stream()
                .filter(object1 -> object2IdList.contains(object1.getobject2Id()))
                .map(Object1::getobject3Id).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice. Why is your solution preferred to the accepted one? Right now it's just a code dump....

Comment: You are right. I will delete it.